# Eclipse rcp : IFolderLayout, how to keep folder open when all views in it are closed

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I created a **IFolderLayout** in my perspective, when user close all views in that folder, the folder itself will be closed too. bu t I want it to be remained there.

```
layout.setEditorAreaVisible(false);
        IFolderLayout functionsViewFolder = layout.createFolder("functionsViewsFolder", IPageLayout.RIGHT, 0.2f, layout.getEditorArea());
        functionsViewFolder.addPlaceholder(FunctionView.ID + ":" + FunctionView.SECONDARY_ID + "*");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override this in your  WorkbenchWindowAdvisor

```
public boolean isDurableFolder(String perspectiveId, String folderId) {
  return true;
}
```

by default, this is returned as false and hence the folder closes when all the views in the folder are closed.

Override this method and either restrict to a particular folder /perspective or return true as above to force this behaviour to all perspectives/folder